# How do I select a question with particular tags?

Tags: support, tags

I want to select questions that are only tagged as SQL, SQLServer, SQLSever 2008. I am not interested in questions that have anything more than these tags. How do i select such questions only ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql+or+sql-server-2008+or+sql-server You're welcome.

Comment: Actually, this may be more of what you're looking for: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/105264

Comment: Do I have to always modify the url to get what i want ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql+or+sql-server-2008+or+sql-server
that is change the or to and, and add or remove tags in the url ? I tried using ALL AND and got the three tags plus extras - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql+and+sql-server-2008+and+sql-server

Comment: No, that URL was obtained via the search box, with this query: `[sql] or [sql-server] or [sql-server-2008]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start by defining your favorite tags.  Over to the right in the sidebar you will see your favorite and ignored tags.

[image]

If you haven't set any up yet you'll see something similar to this:

[image]

Click on "Add a favorite tag" and add your tags.  It's a good idea to fill out your ignored list too.

[image]

After you've added your favorite tags click "edit" then "advanced tag subscriptions".

[image]
[image]

From here you can specify questions that fall into your favorite tags, what site they're on, and whether you want a list emailed to you.
[image]

And after filling this out you'll get a special page with just questions tagged with your favorite tags.

[image]

If you would like to get an email about new questions in an individual tag, you can subscribe to that tag from the [tags page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) or get an RSS feed.

[image]

Another method (perhaps easier) would be to search:

```
[sql] or [sql-server] or [sql-server-2008]
```