# How do I select questions with a particular combination of tags?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags

I need to select questions with only particular tags. I need help to select questions which have SQL along with SQL Server and SQL Server 2008. Questions that have any other tags must not be selected. I saw [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173918/how-do-i-select-a-question-with-particular-tags), but I also get questions that have a phpadmin, C#, etc. I am confused. How do I do it?

[Here](https://stackexchange.com/filters/118557/sqlnsqlserver) is URL for my filter.

Comment: You already did add phpadmin and c# to your ignored tags list as explained in the post you linked?

Comment: did you try: Advanced tag subscriptions

Comment: @rene - I have remove those tags from my list. But there are so many tag. I cannot add all. It is a pain.

Comment: @user689 - yes, I have try that. It not work as desire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is currently not exactly/easily possible but there are feature-requests [asking for similar functionality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105548/searching-for-question-having-strictly-a-certain-set-of-tag)

You could try to fine tune your results by adding tags to you ignored tags list. If that doesn't suits your needs you could have a look at this [Data Explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/164352/posts-with-only-sql-or-sql-server) that shows now 1000 questions that have no other tags than [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) or [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server) or [sql-server-2008](/questions/tagged/sql-server-2008).

<sup>You can change the number of rows returned by increasing the number after SELECT TOP 1000 but do remember that the query might time out if procesing takes too long</sup>

Comment: Thanks rene. Is there a way I can get more than just a top 100 ?

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev fixed and added how you can adapt the number of rows your self